# Using data annotations localization in ASP.NET core v1.0.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm trying to localise my APS.NET core application, I've succefully added the view localisation which is working however the DataAnnotation localisation doesn't appear to be working.

I've been following the [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/localization.html#dataannotations-localization) unfortunately its not overly clear especially lines such as:

The runtime doesn’t look up localized strings for non-validation attributes. In the code above, “Email” (from [Display(Name = "Email")]) will not be localized.

So I'm not sure what is missing, here's the appropriate sections from my Startup file:

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

        services.AddMvc()
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "de-DE", uiCulture: "de-DE");
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });
```

and

```
private readonly CultureInfo[] supportedCultures = { new CultureInfo("en-GB"), new CultureInfo("en-US"), new CultureInfo("en"), new CultureInfo("de"), new CultureInfo("fr") };

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialises the localisation features.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app">
    /// The app to be localized.
    /// </param>
    private void InitialiseLocalisation(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseRequestLocalization(
            new RequestLocalizationOptions
                {
                    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("de-DE"),
                    //// Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
                    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
                    //// UI strings that we have localized.
                    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
                });
    }
```

which is called in Configure.

The resources are set up as follows:

[image: Resoures]

As you can see the view is localised but the data annotations aren't:

[image]

ViewModel:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

/// <summary>
/// Class LoginViewModel.
/// </summary>
public class LoginViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the email.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The email.</value>
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the password.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The password.</value>
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the service should remember the user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> if the service should remember the user; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@using System.Collections.Generic
@using System.Threading.Tasks
@using Ebase.IdentityService.Models
@using Ebase.IdentityService.Models.Account
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@model Ebase.IdentityService.Models.Account.LoginViewModel

@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = Localizer["Login"];
}

<h1 class="chevron-right">@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <section>
            <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <h4>@Localizer["Log in"]</h4>
                <hr />
                <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Email" class="col-md-12"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Password" class="col-md-12"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-12">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input asp-for="RememberMe" />
                            <label asp-for="RememberMe"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-7 pull-right">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">@Localizer["Log in"]</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                    <a asp-action="Register" asp-route-returnUrl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]">@Localizer["Register as a new user?"]</a>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a asp-action="ForgotPassword">@Localizer["Forgot your password?"]</a>
                </p>
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section>
            <img src="https://portal.company.com/homepage/login.jpg" class="login-bild">
        </section>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section>
            <h4>Use another service to log in.</h4>
            <hr />
            @{
                var loginProviders = SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemes().ToList();
                if (loginProviders.Count == 0)
                {
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            There are no external authentication services configured. See <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715">this article</a>
                            for details on setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="ExternalLogin" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                @foreach (var provider in loginProviders)
                                {
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="provider" value="@provider.AuthenticationScheme" title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">@provider.AuthenticationScheme</button>
                                }
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                }
            }
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts { @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }}
```

Resource: LoginViewModel.de.resx

[image: LoginViewModel.de.resx]

Comment: Can you show the view model/model complete with annotations and the Razor code for rendering the registration form? This does not need to be the full model, only the email, password and confirmation properties.

Comment: Hey how did you fix this? I'm having the same problem